# How can I run SharePoint tests using the NUnit Test Adapter for Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, nunit, test-explorer

The [NUnit Test Adapter](http://nunit.org/index.php?p=vsTestAdapter&r=2.6.2) for VS 2012 allows you to run NUnit tests from within the Visual Studio 2012 IDE via the Test Explorer. However, the reason I have NUnit tests in the first place is because I have tests written against SharePoint 2010 (I know, these are Integration Tests, not Unit Tests), which, due to the requirement that the SharePoint API be accessed through a 64-bit client means that MSTest/VS can't run them.

I was hoping that with the NUnit Test Adapter, however, I would be able to run the SharePoint tests from within Test Explorer in Visual Studio but I keep getting the error message:

```
SetUp failed for test fixture xyz
SetUp : System.IO.FileNotFoundException : The Web application at http://sp could not be found. Verify that you have typed the URL correctly. If the URL should be serving existing content, the system administrator may need to add a new request URL mapping to the intended application.
```

This indicates to me that the NUnit Test Adapter is running as a 32-bit process (I suspect the process is `vstest.executionengine.x86.clr20.exe`).

Is there any way to run NUnit tests that target SharePoint 2010 using the NUnit Test Adapter and Test Explorer in Visual Studio 2012?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run tests in 64-bit process:

- In Visual Studio 2012, select TEST->Test Settings->Default Processor Architecture->x64 menu item
- With vstest.console.exe, specify /Platform:x64 command line option.

You may also be interested in [SharePoint Emulators](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/11/26/introducing-sharepoint-emulators.aspx), which allow you run SharePoint integration tests in isolation.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks! Can't use the Emulators though - I don't have VS 2012 Ultimate right now...